# iOS App in flutter crashes during launch trying to configure Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I've a few apps connected to my firebase project. Recently one of those apps..an iOS app... crashes while launching on my simulator. The output is:

```
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        20.3s
Xcode build done.                                           59.8s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
[Crashlytics] Version 3.14.0 (144)
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:57399/MD_uhGLIBGA=/
```

The iOS app doesn't have Crashlytics or Fabric installed. So I presume it's something that's changed with firebase. I added a web app to the project which has analytics installed(not Crashlytics). I think it's since then my problem started. Is there a way for my client app to " forget" about the crashlytics service?

Comment: Chintan from Firebase. This log would only show up if Fabric.with statement was called. Can you double check?

Comment: Thanks Cintan, there is actually a shared folder between apps(one of the apps is mine). firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3 is a dependency in the pubspec of that shared folder. No sign of fabrics though.